Upgrade from HP 6300 pro SFF with broken PSU
I currently have a refurbished HP Pro 6300 SFF pc with Intel Core i5-3470 processor and 16GB of RAM that I've had for 4 years (presumably used in an office before that).
Unfortunately, my PSU is slowly dying and I can't easily find a replacement for it in my area. On top of that, due to changing requirements (more graphics processing in Gimp/Inkscape) the performance has been a larger and larger bottleneck. This is why I'm now looking for a replacement.
While researching online, I found that the tower form factor offers better options for future updates and a wider range of components that can be substituted if something fails (like my PSU). Also, it's easier to fit a graphics card if I need that in the future.
My requirements are:

At least the same performance as I have now, preferably somewhat better (better suited to image processing/vector illustrations).
Needs to run Linux.
Preferably good upgradability / easy to replace components that break in the future. I prefer replacing components to buying a new system every 4 years.
Needs to fit at least two standard HDD's and one SSD.
Ethernet port, displayport or HDMI. Approximately the same amount / more USB ports (now 4 front, 6 rear).
I favor sustainable/eco-friendly replacement options, i.e. refurbished (I prefer this to second hand because of warranty), reusing as much of the hardware as possible etc.
The budget depends on if it's an upgrade or not, but approximately around 200 - 400 euros.

Therefore, I'm considering the following options to solve my problem:

Buy a refurbished HP Pro 6300 micro tower and swap over the components. Pro: larger form factor, can only buy the case + PSU and transfer all other components, very cheap (~30 euros). Con: not an upgrade in terms of hardware now, still only 3rd generation Intel.
Buy a refurbished HP EliteDesk 800 G3 Micro Tower with 6th gen Intel i5 and 16 or 32 GB of RAM. Pro: larger form factor, upgrade in terms of specs. Con: can only transfer SSD's/HDD's, slightly more expensive (165 euros for 16GB, 245 euros for 32GB RAM).
I've also read that both Dell and HP (brands available for refurbished PC's where I live) have a lot of proprietary components that may not be easily replaceable in the future. Therefore, the other option would be to buy a custom case + a custom PSU (with an ATX power adapter cable to connect it to the motherboard) and transfer the current components there. I have no idea if this is possible / advisable. Pro: modular system, can easily replace or upgrade components, totally customizable. Con: probably not available refurbished, more expensive.

Please let me know what your thoughts are and if there's anything I'm missing out on.
